# Memoization of a single parameter in a multi-parameter function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

I am solving [this programming problem](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/189/A), and I am exceeding the time limit with my current solution. I believe that the solution to my problem is memoization. However, I do not understand the memoization solutions documented [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Memoization).

Here is the primary function in my current solution.

```
maxCuts :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
maxCuts n a b c  
    | n == 0    = 0
    | n < 0     = -10000
    | otherwise = max (max amax bmax) cmax
    where 
        amax = 1 + maxCuts (n - a) a b c
        bmax = 1 + maxCuts (n - b) a b c
        cmax = 1 + maxCuts (n - c) a b c
```

This function takes too long to run if a b and c are small relative to n. I would just copy the solution they used for the factorial function, but that function only takes one parameter. I have four parameters, but I only want to key the memoiziation on the first parameter, `n`. Notice that `a` `b` and `c` do not change in the recursive calls.

Comment: The simplest thing to do is just uncurry the function so there is, in fact, only one argument: `maxCuts :: (Int, Int, Int, Int) -> Int`

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite your function definition like this:

```
 maxCuts :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
 maxCuts n a b c = maxCuts' n where
     maxCuts' n
          | n == 0    = 0
          | n < 0     = -10000
          | otherwise = max (max amax bmax) cmax
            where 
               amax = 1 + maxCuts' (n - a)  
               bmax = 1 + maxCuts' (n - b) 
               cmax = 1 + maxCuts' (n - c)
```

Now you have a one-argument function you can memoize.

Answer (score 0):

Aside: Isn't your algorithm just computing something like `div n (minimum [a,b,c])`?

As you pointed out, the parameters a, b and c don't change, so first rewrite the function to place the parameter `n` at the end.

If you decide to use a list to memoize the function values it requires
a little care to make sure GHC will save the mapped list:

```
import Debug.Trace

maxCuts' :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
maxCuts' a b c n = memoized_go n
  where
    memoized_go n
      | n < 0 = -10000
      | otherwise =  mapped_list !! n

    mapped_list = map go [0..]

    go n | trace msg False = undefined
      where msg = "go called for " ++ show n
    go 0 = 0
    go n = maximum [amax, bmax, cmax]
      where
        amax = 1 + memoized_go (n-a)
        bmax = 1 + memoized_go (n-b)
        cmax = 1 + memoized_go (n-c)

test1 = print $ maxCuts' 1 2 3 10
```

Note the circular dependency of the definitions: `memoized_go` depends on `mapped_list` which depends on `go` which depends on `memozied_go`.

Since lists only admit non-negative indexes, the case `n < 0` has to be
handled in a separate guard pattern.

The `trace` calls show that `go` is only called once per value of `n`.
For instance, consider trying to do this without defining `mapped_list`:

```
maxCuts2 :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
maxCuts2 a b c n = memoized_go n
  where
    memoized_go n
      | n < 0 = -10000
      | otherwise =  (map go [0..]) !! n
    -- mapped_list = map go [0..]
    go n | trace msg False = undefined
      where msg = "go called for " ++ show n
    go 0 = 0
    go n = maximum [amax, bmax, cmax]
      where
        amax = 1 + memoized_go (n-a)
        bmax = 1 + memoized_go (n-b)
        cmax = 1 + memoized_go (n-c)

test2 = print $ maxCuts2 1 2 3 11
```

Running `test2` shows that `go` is called multiple times for the same value of `n`.

**Update**

To avoid creating large unevaluated thunks, I would use BangPatterns
for `amax`, `bmax` and `cmax`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

maxCuts' ... =
  ...
  where
    !amax = 1 + ...
    !bmax = 1 + ...
    !cmax = 1 + ...
```